# why I cannot overload the << operator in another file?

Tags: c++

I am getting an error when trying to overload the << operator from another file where I use the operator and do not understand why.

This code works

(foo.hpp)

```
#ifndef FOO_HPP
#define FOO_HPP
enum class Foo { a, b };
#endif
```

(bar.cpp)

```
#include "foo.hpp"
#include <iostream>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Foo x) {
  switch(x) {
  case Foo::a :
    out << "a";
    break;
  case Foo::b :
    out << "b";
    break;
  }
  return out;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  Foo x {Foo::a};
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

(Makefile)

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=--std=c++11 -Wall

bar : bar.o 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) bar.o -o bar

bar.o : bar.cpp foo.hpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c bar.cpp foo.hpp
```

(output of ./bar)

```
a
```

Now, if I create foo.cpp, and move the definition of `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& , Foo)` there, and modify my Makefile this way

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=--std=c++11 -Wall

bar : bar.o foo.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) bar.o foo.o -o bar

foo.o : foo.cpp foo.hpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c foo.cpp foo.hpp

bar.o : bar.cpp foo.hpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c bar.cpp foo.hpp
```

It does not work and I get a ton of compiler errors starting with

```
bar.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
bar.cpp:6:13: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘Foo’)
   std::cout << x << std::endl;
             ^
```

and very similar other errors.

Why ?

Comment: do you have the includes right? i.e. `#include <iostream>` in foo.cpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator <<` is still a function like any other (with some additional properties). Its declaration must be visible in all files which want to use it. So if you move its definition from `main.cpp` into `foo.cpp`, you will need to put a declaration for it in `foo.hpp`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Foo x);
```

Answer (score 0):

adding extern std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,Foo); in bar.cpp fixed it and it works.